# Как вставить в строку переменную JS?

Tags: javascript, строки

У меня есть вот такая вещь:

```
$('.table').find('tbody').find("tr[t-id='сюды переменная']").find("td:eq(1)").text(100)
```

Мне нужно вставить в строку, которая равна `t-id`, переменную.

Я пробовал через `replace` и `replaceObject` даже просто через фигурные скобки, но я получаю ошибку: `is not a function`.

Comment: каково значение переменной

Answer (score 2):

```
var myVar = 25;
$('.table').find('tbody').find("tr[t-id='" + myVar + "']").find("td:eq(1)").text(100)
```

Comment: если писать через " + myVar + " (две двойных кавычки) то сам код `$('.table').find('tbody').find("tr[t-id='" + myVar + "']").find("td:eq(1)").text(100)` выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: @Diq, сейчас будет глупый вопрос: вы вместо myVar подставили настоящую переменную? Второй вопрос: вы подключили `jQuery`?

Answer (score 2):

Можно через новый синтаксис интерполяции строк

```
var myId = "exampleId";
$('.table').find('tbody').find(`tr[t-id='${ myId }']`).find("td:eq(1)").text(100)
```